# Check if module is enabled

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, joomla-api

I'm currently trying to check if a specific module is enabled by using Joomla's `JModuleHelper::isEnabled()`, however the problem being is that it is always returning **false**, despite whether it is actually enabled or not.

Having looked at the [Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/isEnabled), I've written the following:

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');        
$freichat = JModuleHelper::isEnabled('FreiChat-I');

if($freichat) {
    $message = 'Enabled';
}
else {
    $message = 'Disabled';
}

$application = JFactory::getApplication();
$application->enqueueMessage( $message, 'warning');
```

I've tried changing `FreiChat-I` to `login`, which then always returns **true**, despite being enabled or disabled.

Is there a known bug that I'm unaware of or am I simply doing something stupid here?

Comment: IMO the Joomla team should rename this function to `isAvailable` as the example in the link you provided  says that "Login module is available". The returned value of this function has 3 criterias which "is enabled" is only one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JModuleHelper::isEnabled()` does not seem to account for any type of case sensitivity. So for example, using @Bakual's answer, your options are actually either `mod_breadcrumbs` or `breadcrumbs` (not `Breadcrumbs`)

Likewise, in your case, you would want to do `JModuleHelper::isEnabled('freichat')`. From looking at the table, everything will always be lowercase, so if you pass in a capital letter, you will get `false`.

Also, note that the extension not only has to be installed and enabled, but there much be an instance of the module published on the site.

Comment: I've tried `mod_*` along with making it lower case too. My answer below explains a little

Answer (score 4):

The API page is here: http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModuleHelper.html#method_isEnabled

You need to either pass the name of the module or the folder of it. So for the breadcrumbs module it would be either 'Breadcrumbs' or 'mod_breadcrumbs'. You can't use the title of the module.

Without knowing the name or folder of your module, I can't tell you more.

Comment: What I have provided is already the name of the module and I've also tried using the folder (mod_freichatx). the odd thing being is if I change it to `Breadcrumbs`, it still doesn't work and always returns false

Answer (score 2):

[`public static function isEnabled($module);`](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModuleHelper.html#method_isEnabled)

> Checks if a module is enabled. A given module will only be returned if
>   it meets the following criteria: it is enabled, it is assigned to the
>   current menu item or all items, and the user meets the access level
>   requirements.

### Update

You can use a db query instead:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `published` FROM `#__modules` WHERE `title` = 'Breadcrumbs'");
$is_enabled = $db->loadResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for taking them time to answer.

Having looked at the `#__extensions` table, I noticed that the `enabled` column was not being updated, even when I had, disabled a module, removed its position and unassigned it from all pages.

In the end, I decided to run a database query to check the existence of `mod_freichatx` in the table and display the `enqueueMessage` accordingly.

Comment: Were you disabling the modules from the extension manager or the module manager? The module manager affects the `#__modules` table, and specifically the `published` column, not the #__extensions table.

Comment: @DavidFritsch - Just noticed that I have to disable it via the Extension Manager but still nothing. It does work with `mod_login` but returns false for `mod_breadcrumbs`. I think I might test this on a new installation of Joomla tomorrow. Thanks for your input.